# Android FrameLayout overlays photo over another

Tags: android, image, overlay, android-framelayout

I'm trying to place one image over the other image ivImage is from the drawable and imageView1 is from gallery. I want imView to be on top of imageView1. I have tryed android:layout_weight="1" but did not work among other answer i have searched. trying to do this in xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNextPhoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="nextPhoto"
        android:text="Next" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPrevPhoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="PrevPhoto"
        android:text="Prev" />

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    </FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

     <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
           android:layout_height="200dp"
           android:layout_width="200dp"
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:scaleType="centerCrop"
           android:layout_weight="-1" />

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_width="300dp"            
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
            android:onClick="loadImagefromGallery"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="photo">
    </Button> 


      </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes

```
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
```

are not relevant in FrameLayout, replace it with

```
    android:layout_gravity="center"
```